# How do I force ansible to retry an 'apt' task if it fails?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt

I have an `ansible` playbook running on many machines. In that playbook I have a few packages I am trying to install using `apt`, but occasionally they fail, either because other playbooks are running, a periodic update or any other `apt` instance running in parallel and grabbing the lock.

I basically want to add a retry loop before giving up but failed to do so as retries is not supported for `apt`, apparently: I looked into the `apt module` page in [ansible's documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_module.html), and even tried to actually use it even though it is not there (which obviously failed).

Anyway - I need an idea on how to get ansible to retry for let's say 3 times, with 30 seconds delay, but only on failures to install the package.

Comment: Adding data: I found a way to do the retries and delay on the apt (missed 2 spaces in the indentation), but am still missing the part of how to know that apt succeeded. I thought that checking the rc is 0 would be enough, it is not. Can I rely on the stderr to be empty?

Answer (score 21):

There are universal [task results tests](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tests.html#task-results), so you can use:

```
- apt:
    name: build-essential
    state: present
  register: apt_res
  retries: 5
  until: apt_res is success
```

[With Ansible 2.4 and earlier use the filter syntax - this was deprecated in Ansible 2.5 and will be removed from 2.9](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#jinja-tests-used-as-filters)

```
until: apt_res | success
```