# How can I avoid duplication of retry logic in Ansible tasks?

Tags: ansible

In my Ansible playbook I've been running into intermittent failures with `apt` tasks due to failures to obtain a lock.

I'm thinking of using some retry logic as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47556023). e.g.

```
- name: install packages
  apt:
    name:
      - nginx
      - git
  register: result
  until: result is not failed
  retries: 7
  delay: 9
```

The playbook includes multiple `apt` tasks so I'm wondering if there's a way that I can avoid repeating the `register`, `retries`, `until` for each `apt` task i.e. some way to make these defaults, or to define my own `apt-with-retries`?

My playbook is for provisioning DigitalOcean droplets. I've got several `apt` tasks due to:

- Breaking down the playbook into logic steps i.e. apt install a few things, followed by a few other steps, followed by apt installing another group of packages...
- I've extracted a couple of roles into their own self-contained files e.g. a `postgres_server` role.

The goals here are the usual reasons for wanting to avoid duplication/repetition. e.g. avoid having to make changes in multiple places, avoid having to remember to copy and paste when adding another apt task in the future.

I looked into using `module_defaults`, but these properties are on the task itself rather than the `apt` module so I don't think they can be used for this scenario.

Comment: Would be more informative if you could explain better what you have and what are your goals. For example for grouping all the apt taks maybe you should consider the use of [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) where you can set register, until, retries, delay in one same place for all of them.

Comment: Consider addressing `failed to obtain lock` issue

Comment: @P...., it's a well-known problem for apt. There are tons of sources of lock issues (unattended updates, etc), so retries is the most robust solution for ansible-apt failures.

Comment: Hi @malpanez. Thanks for taking a look at my question. I've updated the question with a bit more background context. Blocks sound interesting, and certainly something that it's useful to know about, but I don't think they would help here due to the `apt` tasks being spread out.

Comment: @P.... you're right of course. Ideally I would address the underlying issue if I could, but I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/51663) and it seems to be an ongoing discuss with various folks posting ideas and workarounds. As George Shuklin mentioned there are multiple causes of lock issues. e.g. One of the things I'd tried is adding a task that disabled unattended updates at the start of the playbook. I think that helped a bit, but there must still be other causes I haven't got to the bottom of yet.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeShuklin. It's at least reassuring to know that this is a well known problem and that I'm on a reasonable track.

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of apt module has support for retries at module level:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-lock_timeout

Default is 60.

Comment: In detail, as of v2.12.

Comment: Thanks, George. I'm on 2.13.3 so should have this. If the default is 60 then I must be already hitting that limit. Will give it a go with a higher value and see if it helps.